# How to do find_index for multiple values in a Ruby array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, find

Given an array `[0, 0, 1, 0, 1]`, is there a built-in method to get all of the indexes of values greater than 0? So, the method should return `[2, 4]`.

`find_index` only returns the first match.

Working in Ruby 1.9.2.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9, iterator methods called without a block return an `Enumerator` object. So you could do something like:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1].each_with_index.select { |num, index| num > 0 }.map { |pair| pair[1] }
# => [2, 4]
```

Stepping through:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1].each_with_index
# => #<Enumerator: [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]:each_with_index>
_.select { |num, index| num > 0 }
# => [[1, 2], [1, 4]]
_.map { |pair| pair[1] }
# => [2, 4]
```

Comment: `.map(&:last)` would be a good replacement for `.map { |pair| pair[1] }` if you wanted to cut down the noise a bit.

Answer (score 7):

I would do

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1].map.with_index{|x, i| i if x > 0}.compact
```

And if you want that as a single method, ruby does not have a built in one, but you can do:

```
class Array
    def select_indice &p; map.with_index{|x, i| i if p.call(x)}.compact end
end
```

and use it as:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1].select_indice{|x| x > 0}
```